# Prolog - Check winning condition in X and O game

Tags: prolog

I have a simple game of tic tac toe, there are many examples of this online that use min maxing however I just want to use a simple example for my own understanding.
I have displayed the board in a 3x3 box that have numbering system that users can pick from, in the following way:

```
:- dynamic o/1.
:- dynamic x/1.

% The computer has made a turn, print O
printBox(N) :- o(N), write('[o]').
% The player makes a turn, print X
printBox(N) :- x(N), write('[x]').
% We just want to print the empty board
printBox(N) :- blankSpace(N), write('[_]').


buildBoard :- printBox(1),printBox(2),printBox(3),nl,
          printBox(4),printBox(5),printBox(6),nl,
          printBox(7),printBox(8),printBox(9),nl.

playersMove :- 
read(X), 
blankSpace(X), 
assert(x(X)).
```

When a user select from the above options (1-9) the board is filled with an X for the human player and O for the computer. 
Now I also have facts for the winning lines:

```
winningLine(1,2,3).
winningLine(4,5,6).
winningLine(7,8,9).
%Winning rows from left to right
winningLine(1,4,7).
winningLine(2,5,8).
winningLine(3,6,9).
%Winning diagnolly
winningLine(7,5,3).
winningLine(9,5,1).
```

So after each move I want to check if one of the winning line combinations has been played ie does the board contain any of the winningLine combinations and with player has that combination. I have been thinking about it and a findall method could be used here however I would be open to suggestion.

My Question: How do I check the board for the winning conditions?

Comment: I think simple pattern matching will probably be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, would you be able to help me understand how this could be done on one of the WinningLine rules?

Comment: how exactly do you represent your board? How do you represent `x`, `o` and blank?

Comment: I have updated the question with some more code to show you this.

Basically, I have dynamic X and O variable, when the board is created I place in a string ' [ ] ' When the user inputs a number between 1 - 9 the board is rebuilt aserting the [X] into the place of the blank number

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a good approach, since here you create a *global state*, it will also result in a lot of `assert/1`s and `retract/1`s, and mistakes are easily made, especially if you want to search for a solution. A more *Prolog-ical* solution is constructing an object that you pass through calls, and update/unify.

Comment: I understand that this may not be the best approach however I am just learning and trying to get my head around it

There will be no retracts as once the user inputs the number it will only assert the X or O, which is already done.

Comment: shouln't you retract the `blankSpace/1` for the item you wish to fill in?

Comment: No because I am rebuilding the board each time the user inputs the number, the code just asserts the symbol

Comment: But in order to rebuild the board, you need to destroy (at least part of) the board, hene retracting (or another mechanism to remove facts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above *global state* representation, you basically have to call the `winningLine(I, J, K)` to obtain a triple of *indices*, then for all these indices, either `x(X)` (with `X` replaced by `I`, `J` and `K`) should hold; or for all indices `o(X)` should hols, like:

```
xwin :-
    winningLine(I, J, K),
    x(I),
    x(J),
    x(K).
nwin :-
    winningLine(I, J, K),
    o(I),
    o(J),
    o(K).
win :-
    xwin.
win :-
    owin.
```

So here `xwin/0` is satisfied, given the player for `x` has a winning line, `owin/0` is satisfied, given the player for `o` has a winning line, and `win/0` is satisfied if any of the players has won.

But personally I think using a global state is not an elegant way to solve problems (actually in most, if not all programming paradigms). Here you can not make use of Prolog's powerful backtracking mechanism, and furthermore if you for example would like to search if there still exists a way how a user can win, you can thus not simply duplicate the board, and run a solver on the duplicated board.

Comment: If I could just get this right, in the xwin function you are taking in the winningLine that I have made and then comparing the I,J,K to the numbers.

Am I correct there?

Comment: Well we check if for `I`, `J` and `K`, `x(I)`, `x(J)` and `x(K)` hold, so that these boxes are all marked with an `x`, if that is not the case, Prolog will backtrack, and keep looking for a winning line, until all the lines are exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

## The simple answer

Since you are working with a global game position, we can assume the existence of a predicate `checked(Player, Square)` which holds iff player `Player` has checked the square `Square`.

Then all you need to check in order to see if a player has won the game is to ask whether there is a winning line where all three squares are checked by the same player:

```
is_win(Player) :-
    winning_line(P1,P2,P3),
    checked(Player,P1),
    checked(Player,P2),
    checked(Player,P3).
```

You can generate `checked/2` by use of `assertz`:

```
:- dynamic checked/2.

player_move(Player, Square) :- assertz(checked(Player, Square)).
```

## The better Way

However, if you want to go beyond simulating a simple game you should represent your state in a single data item and not put in in the global database, for example:

```
initial_state(board([empty, empty, empty],
                    [empty, empty, empty],
                    [empty, empty, empty]).
```

and adjust `player_move` and `checked` accordingly:

```
/* Should make a new board from Position0 by adding the move */
player_move(Player, Square, Position0, Position) :- ...  

/* Should check if a player has checked a square inside Position */
checked(Player, Square, Position) :- ...
```

Comment: Hi firefrorefiddle, thank you for the answer, it helped with my understanding, I am giving the correct answer to the other user as he helped me through the understanding of the question but I appreciate your help